# Constructing a regular expression for url in start_urls list in scrapy framework python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new to scrapy and also i didn't used regular expressions before

The following is my `spider.py` code

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "test_code
   allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/1?filter=bookstore",
       "http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/2?filter=bookstore",
       "http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/3?filter=bookstore",
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

Now if we look at `start_urls` all the three urls are same except they differ at integer value `2?, 3?` and so on i mean unlimited according to urls present on the site , i now that we can use crawlspider and we can construct regular expression for the URL like below,

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    import re

    class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'example.com'
        allowed_domains = ['example.com']
        start_urls = [
       "http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/1?filter=bookstore",
       "http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/2?filter=bookstore",
       "http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/3?filter=bookstore",
   ]

        rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(........),))),
        ) 

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

can u please guide me , that how can i construct a crawl spider Rule for the above `start_url` list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want a lot of start URL with a certain pattern.

If so, you can override [BaseSpider.start_requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method:

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "test_code"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in xrange(1000):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.example.com/bookstore/new/%d?filter=bookstore" % i)

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much its very useful for me i got my output

Comment: Sure i will vote , how can we make that value for xrange unlimited, because actually i had 20 items(limited to) per page(If extra items are added on the page a URL with incremented interger will be created as shown in the above example) , and integer which is present in URL will contiune to increase.so is there a way to make that range as infinte.

Comment: An infinite number means infinite processing time. If you are still sure, make a loop: `i = 0; while True: yield ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CrawlSpider, it's not usually a good idea to override the parse method.

Rule object can filter the urls you are interesed to the ones you do not care for.

See [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) in the docs for reference.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import re

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/bookstore']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\/new\/[0-9]\?',)), callback='parse_bookstore'),
    )

def parse_boostore(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

Comment: SgmlLinkExtractor has been deprecated for some time now.