# Scrapy Spider authenticate and iterate

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

Below is a Scrapy spider I have put together to pull some elements from a web page. I borrowed this solution from [another Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738560/constructing-a-regular-expression-for-url-in-strat-url-list-in-scrapy-framework). It works, but I need more. I need to be able to walk the series of pages specified in the for loop inside the start_requests method after authenticating.

Yes, I did locate the [Scrapy documentation discussing this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) along with a previous solution for [something very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850755/using-scrapy-with-authenticated-logged-in-user-session). Neither one seems to make much sense. From what I can gather, I need to somehow create a request object and keep passing it along, but cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import re

class MyBasicSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "awBasic"
    allowed_domains = ["americanwhitewater.org"]

    def start_requests(self):
        '''
        Override BaseSpider.start_requests to crawl all reaches in series
        '''
        # for every integer from one to 5000
        for i in xrange(1, 50): # 1 to 50 for testing

            # convert to string
            iStr = str(i)

            # add leading zeros to get to four digit length
            while len(iStr) < 4:
                iStr = '0{0}'.format(iStr)

            # call make requests
            yield self.make_requests_from_url('https://mycrawlsite.com/{0}/'.format(iStr))

    def parse(self, response):

        # create xpath selector object instance with response
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # get part of url string
        url = response.url
        id = re.findall('/(\d{4})/', url)[0]

        # selector 01
        attribute01 = hxs.select('//div[@id="block_1"]/text()').re('([^,]*)')[0]

        # selector for river section
        attribute02 = hxs.select('//div[@id="block_1"]/div[1]/text()').extract()[0]

        # print results
        print('\tID: {0}\n\tAttr01: {1}\n\tAttr02: {2}').format(reachId, river, reachName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to approach the problem from a different angle:

- first of all, scrape the main page; it contains a login form, so you can use [FormRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) to simulate a user login; your `parse` method will likely look something like this:

  ```
  def parse(self, response):
      return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                  formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                  callback=self.after_login)]
  ```
- in `after_login` you check if the authentication was successful, usually by scanning the response for error messages; if all went well and you're logged in, you can start generating requests for the pages you're after:

  ```
  def after_login(self, response):
      if "Login failed" in response.body:
          self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
      else:
          for i in xrange(1, 50): # 1 to 50 for testing
              # convert to string
              iStr = str(i)

              # add leading zeros to get to four digit length
              while len(iStr) < 4:
                  iStr = '0{0}'.format(iStr)

              # call make requests
              yield Request(url='https://mycrawlsite.com/{0}/'.format(iStr),
                            callback=self.scrape_page)
  ```
- `scrape_page` will be called with each of the pages you created a request for; there you can finally extract the information you need using XPath, regex, etc.

BTW, you shouldn't 0-pad numbers manually; `format` will do it for you if you use the right format specifier.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance. It took a bit of tinkering to get it all wired up and working, but now it is humming smoothly.

The only real missing component was needing to re-add the start url at the top and import statements for `Request` and `FormRequest`. This likely is obvious enough, but it took me a few minutes to figure out.

Also, thank you for the hint on using `format`. It did not take very long to find the documentation and examples on use.